# After research, how should I go about creating a bluetooth peripheral?

Tags: bluetooth, microprocessor, bluetooth-low-energy

My goal is to create a very simple (1 input, 1 output, both high / low states) bluetooth peripheral to be worn on the wrist to connect to an android phone running Lollipop. I have the following requirements:

- Use either the bluetooth 4.0 or 4.1 standard
- As low power consumption as possible
- Small form factor (worn on the wrist)
- Low cost - this is partly as a challenge for myself to find the lowest possible cost to achieve this

With the above in mind, I have come up with the following options:

1. Use an integrated arduino / bluetooth module (e.g. [Blend Micro](http://redbearlab.com/blendmicro/)). This should be easy to do, but falls down on the form factor and cost
2. Use a serial bluetooth module (e.g. [Tinysine's](http://www.tinyosshop.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=705)) with a simple programmable chip, such as the [PICAXE](http://www.picaxe.com/Hardware/PICAXE-Chips/PICAXE-08M2-microcontroller/). This is cheap and has a low form factor, but after researching some of the available bluetooth module options, the datasheets appear to be extremely unhelpful and out of date
3. Use a programmable propriety bluetooth module (e.g. [Rayson BTM-840B](http://www.rayson.com/rayson/en/?pros=product&pros=product&b_cat_id=A01&m_cat_id=A0104&s_cat_id=A010402&prod_id=P0104&level=3)). This should be the smallest and lowest cost, but upon research I am not too sure how to actually purchase any of the supposed options, or actually load my own code on them.

Are there other options that I have not considered? With regards to the third option, what accessible products are there available for this specific purpose, and how can I program them? I am very open to more 'difficult' programming environments, but I am not sure where to even start with this particular scope.

Comment: How many of these are you hoping to make? The TI or Nordic BLE chips are under $3.00 each, and require almost no other parts, they contain a fairly powerful microcontroller. But you need to shell out for a $2000 development suite, and perhaps 2 man-years of debugging. So for a few units, just go for the Arduino module. For many, you can't beat the cost of the raw BLE chip.

Comment: @tomnexus At this stage this is just a personal project, so I wouldn't want to shell out for massive one-time costs. I think I agree with your conclusion though.

Comment: If it was me I would take an agile development method and use the arduino. Proto your personal project. If you find you like the concept enough, then launch a kickstarter and use whatever greatest technology is available at the time.

Answer (score 4):

The [Bluegiga/Silicon Labs BLE113](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/BlueGiga%20PDFs/BLE113.pdf) is quite small:

[image]

and can be purchased [from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/BLE113-A-V1/1446-1028-1-ND/4245526) for $13.78 in single quantities.

It is a BLE 4.0 device and contains an integrated 8051 and can be programmed in a BASIC-like language called BGScript.  I am currently doing a project with one of these and it communicates successfully to an iPhone.  Bluegiga has free example source code for both iOS **and Android** on their web site.  You just have to register.

The current draw is very low; the transmit current is spec'ed at 18 mA max but when I measure the current when connected to the iPhone the average is only around 2 mA since the transmit duty cycle is so low for BLE.  In sleep mode it draws < 1 µA.

It has lots of general purpose I/O pins available, plus I2C, SPI, PWM, and UART interfaces.

The development environment is free, but you need to get a programmer.  Bluegiga has a couple of different development boards that work with the BLE113, but they start at $200.  I suggest instead you get a TI [CC Debugger](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru197h/swru197h.pdf), which is compatible with their programming software.  You can get one [from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?KeyWords=cc-debugger&WT.z_header=search_go) for $50.

[image]

For prototyping, to avoid having to solder the surface mount BLE113 modules I got these breakout modules [from iNMJO](http://www.inmojo.com/store/jeff-rowberg/item/ble113-bluetooth-low-energy-breakout/) for $40:

[image]

which include the BLE113 plus a 10-pin header that is compatible with the CC Debugger.  The board is still quite small, 1 1/4" x 3/4".

Comment: Thanks for the information, I enjoyed researching that. I don't think it'll be my solution in this particular case, but out of curiosity (if you don't mind me asking), roughly what project are you using this on?

Comment: @enigma Sorry, can't say, under an NDA.   May I ask what you didn't like about the BLE113?  I've found it very easy to use.

Comment: I have been looking at it again actually, thanks for the recommendation - certainly not ruled out. How feasible would it be to program the BLE113 without a debugger, interfacing directly with the chip (presumably via a USB/UART converter if necessary)? My previous experience with PICAXE chips was extremely easy in this regard, but I recognise this is a different beast. Currently a very budget limited student!

Comment: @enigma The debugger is needed to program the device.  In order to program it over the UART (it doesn't have USB), you would need to program a bootloader into the 8051, and they don't allow access to the 8051 to the bootloader to update the flash.  So you're stuck with the debugger.